# Generic ResponseTo<T> as Json

Tags: java, json, spring, gson, fasterxml

I am struggling with deserialising a `JSON` object wrapped by a generic result structure:

My `JSON` from the server:

```
{
  "totalsize": 5,
  "data" : [
             {"name":1},
             {"name":2}
           ]
}
```

My `Java` objects from the result:

```
public class ResponseTo<T> {

    public Long totalsize = null;
    public final List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And in this case (could be anything else on another GET request)

```
public class Item {
    public int name;
}
```

In this case the `T` is an `Item`.

How to deserialise a `JSON` payload into this object structure with:
`GSON` and/or `com.fasterxml.jackson`?

I want to have a static method like:

```
public static <T> ResponseTo<T> stringToObject(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz ) {
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    // do some typeadapter function magic
    return gson.fromJson( jsonString, ResponseTo.class );
}
```

which is invoked by

```
ResponseTo<Item> responseTo = stringToObject( <json-string>, Item.class );
```

I only receive `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` as data objects.

What can I do to make it work? - Am I on a wrong way of doing it?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Were below answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a type-token to handle generic cases, because the type information for `T` will be erased by the Java compiler and Gson wouldn't know what type to restore `T` to.

```
Type typeToken = new TypeToken<ResponseTo<Item>>() { }.getType();
ResponseTo<Item> responseTo = stringToObject( <json-string>, typeToken );
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Yes I get the point of type information being erased. Then I would have to write a deserializer for each time I use another response even though each element item is objectable (jsonstring->object) on a default way. And this feels wrong.

Comment: I don't know about GSON; but I know that Jackson supports polymorphic serialization. They do it by adding an attribute to the serialized JSON that helps the deserializer automatically pick the correct class. But of course this would only work when both serialization and deserialization is done with Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

### Gson

You can use internal `com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types` class to implement this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"totalsize\": 5,\n" +
                "  \"data\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"name\": 1\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"name\": 2\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}\n";

        System.out.println(stringToObject(json, Item.class));
    }

    static <T> ResponseTo<T> stringToObject(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        // do some typeadapter function magic
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = $Gson$Types.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(ResponseTo.class, ResponseTo.class, clazz);
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, parameterizedType);
    }
}

class ResponseTo<T> {

    public Long totalsize = null;
    public final List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResponseTo{" +
                "totalsize=" + totalsize +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}

class Item {
    public int name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "name=" + name +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
ResponseTo{totalsize=5, data=[Item{name=1}, Item{name=2}]}
```

### Jackson

In `Jackson` you can do similar method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"totalsize\": 5,\n" +
                "  \"data\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"name\": 1\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"name\": 2\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}\n";

        System.out.println(stringToObject(json, Item.class));
    }

    static <T> ResponseTo<T> stringToObject(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // do some typeadapter function magic
        JavaType responseType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(ResponseTo.class, clazz);
        return mapper.readValue(jsonString, responseType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a type discriminator in the object (i.e. a common field with a unique value in each example) then Jackson `@JsonTypeInfo(JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY...)` will allow you to define where to look and initialisation can pre-register all possible classes with `ObjectMapper.registerSubtypes(Item.class)`. Jackson will then pick the correct one.

If the rule for which type to instantiate is anything more complex than "look in field X" then you must write your own `@JsonTypeResolver` to implement said logic (non-trivial).